# Remove element by the text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I remove an element using jquery by the text in the element.

```
<a href="/">Link1</a>
```

I dont want to remove the element by class or ID. I want to do something like this:

```
$('a').html('Link1').remove()
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**jQuery**

```
$('a:contains("Link1")').remove();
```

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/4s8b1792/21/)**

For more reference please refer [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/).